# Как добавить в название переменную типа double?

Tags: c++, qt, диаграммы

Есть переменная :

```
double U=2;
```

Как ее преобразовать в строчку и добавить в название серии:

```
QLineSeries *diagramaKmpu = new QLineSeries;
diagramaKmpu->setName("скорость ветра:"+U); // добавить в название серии
```

Comment: Есть метод Qstring setnum

Comment: `sprintf` `wsprintf` ?

Comment: ещё возможно [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) пригодится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diagramaKmpu->setName(QString("скорость ветра: %1").arg(U));
```

Если нужно ограничить количество значащих цифр после запятой, например 3-мя, код будет выглядеть так:

```
diagramaKmpu->setName(QString("скорость ветра: %1").arg(U, 0, 'f', 3));
```

Дополнительную информацию можно прочитать по [ссылке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-8).

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.